# Docker + R : why "save" method doesn't work?

Tags: r, docker, save

I have a docker file :

```
FROM rocker/verse:latest
RUN apt-get update 
RUN R -e "install.packages('TraMineR', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('ggthemes', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('ggplot2', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('Rcpp'            , repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('data.table', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('randomForest', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('pROC'            , repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('stringr', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('ggplot2', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('ggthemes', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('TraMineR', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('bipartite', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('tm'            , repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('dummies', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('xgboost', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"

RUN R -e "install.packages('SnowballC', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
```

I build it, and run it and get a container. In this container I run a R file and try to save an object :

```
NdelivIDexcessif<-15 ; 
save(NdelivIDexcessif, file="sauvegardeTest.rda")
```

And this doesn't create any output as I was expecting a "sauvegardeTest.rda" to be created on the current dir.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Docker volumes are intentionally discarded, so to know "if" and "how" data created inside the container might be saved outside the container, we'd need to see the `docker run ...` command. And then likely migrate it to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), as I think it's about sysadmin and not programming.

Comment: Romain, any luck on resolving your issue?

Comment: yep, sorry, my fault : I had an issue in configuring my volumes (we are blind from time to time)

Comment: I totally understand ... I'm trying to migrate orchestrators from `docker-compose` to `kubectl` and often run into problems with volumes or networks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be one of several possible things, the top two (in my mind) are:

1. Docker by default destroys the environment (e.g., changes to the filesystem) when the container is stopped. This can be a benefit to security and code cleanliness and such, but it requires that if you must have file-level persistence after the container is done, you must explicitly set it up.

   With nothing, the file is not found.

   ```
   root@myhost:/tmp/ltest# ll
   total 76
   drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 26 19:08 ./
   drwxrwxrwt 35 root root 69632 Sep 26 19:08 ../


   root@myhost:/tmp/ltest# docker run \
     --rm -it rocker/tidyverse:3.3.3 \
     R -e "save(mtcars, file='mt.rda')"

   R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
   Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
   Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

   R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
   You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
   Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

   R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
   Type 'contributors()' for more information and
   'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

   Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
   Type 'q()' to quit R.

   > save(mtcars, file='mt.rda')
   >
   >

   root@myhost:/tmp/ltest# ll
   total 76
   drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 26 19:08 ./
   drwxrwxrwt 35 root root 69632 Sep 26 19:08 ../
   ```

   However, if you explicitly set a volume or mount point (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag), persistence can be attained.

   ```
   root@myhost:/tmp/ltest# docker run \
     -v /tmp/ltest:/tmp/rtest/ \
     --rm -it rocker/tidyverse:3.3.3 \
     R -e "save(mtcars, file='/tmp/rtest/mt.rda')"

   R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) -- "Another Canoe"
   Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
   Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

   R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
   You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
   Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

   R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
   Type 'contributors()' for more information and
   'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

   Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
   Type 'q()' to quit R.

   > save(mtcars, file='/tmp/rtest/mt.rda')
   >
   >

   root@franz:/tmp/ltest# ls -l
   total 4
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1234 Sep 26 19:04 mt.rda
   ```
2. If you are already mounting it via some mechanism, make sure you set the path in the `save` command or by pre-setting the working directory of the R process:

   ```
   docker run \
     -v /tmp/rtest:/tmp/rtest/ \
     -w /tmp/rtest/ --rm -it \
     rocker/tidyverse:3.3.3 R -e "save(mtcars, file='mt.rda')"
   docker run \
     -v /tmp/rtest:/tmp/rtest/ \
     --rm -ti \
     rocker/tidyverse:3.3.3 R -e "save(mtcars, file='/tmp/rtest/mt.rda')"
   ```

Note that the location of the directory outside and inside the container are unique; though you can make them the same, there is no requirement to do so. In this example, the *real* directory outside the container is `/tmp/ltest/`, and the name of the internal directory is `/tmp/rtest/`.